# C++ lists error

Tags: c++

I got a project and have to do several operations with "huge" numbers without and use of STL or classes. I've barely started and it doesn't seem to work when i try to print a list where I've saved a number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct NOD{int info;
           NOD *urm;};

void adauga(NOD *&prim, int inf)
{
    NOD *c = new NOD;
    c->info = inf;
    c->urm = prim;
    prim = c;
}

 void adauga2(char sir[4096], NOD* prim)
 {int i;
 // strcpy(sir, strrev(sir));
  for(i=0; i<strlen(sir); i++)
    adauga(prim, sir[i]-'0');}


void afisare(NOD* prim)
{  while(prim!=NULL)
 {cout<<prim -> info;
   prim = prim -> urm;}
}

/*int suma(NOD *p1, NOD *p2, NOD *s)
{int c = 0;

 if(p1->urm != NULL)
    c = suma(p1->urm, p2->urm, s->urm);

 c = c + p1->info + p2->info;

 s->info = c % 10;

 c= c/10;

 return c;
}*/

int main()
{ char s1[4096], s2[4096], s3[4096], s4[4097];
  int i, semn1, semn2;
  NOD* prim1 = NULL;
  NOD* prim2 = NULL;
  NOD* prim3 = NULL;
  NOD* prim4 = NULL;
  NOD* suma = NULL;

  cout<<"Introduceti numaratorul primului numar : ";
  cin>>s1;
  adauga2(s1, prim1);
  afisare(prim1);
 cout<<endl;

  //cout<<"Introduceti numitorul primului numar : ";
 // cin>>s2;
 //adauga2(s2,prim2);

  //cout<<suma(prim1, prim2, suma);


 return 0;
}
```

At the end of this code there's nothing printed, buut if i use "adauga2" INSIDE "afisare"(the function which prints) it works and I really wish to know why. Besides that, I wish to know if it would be a good idea to memorise the strlen value in each list, cause I think that might help alot in the long run. Thx in advance and sorry for the long nooby code, I'm still new in this world :s.

EDIT: I copied all the code now, hope it helps...

Comment: show the code for `strrev`. If it is a function to reverse in-place then your use of it causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Not in standard C++, or POSIX. Maybe it is some extension of your compiler .

Comment: @MattMcNabb i'm pretty sure strrev is in string. h and even with it commented it still doesn't print anything. The bad part is that if I debug it just gives a don't send error. I used both CodeBlocks and Visual Studio 2010 and same thing

Comment: If you can remove code and still get the problem then you have not posted a **minimal** example as described in the [posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you post the exact code too, if you "copied wrongly" then people are not looking at the actual code that has the problem.

Comment: All that is missing are some commented out functions and comments in my language that I thought not to be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `adauga2` must have a reference to the `prim` of main. Otherwise it receives a copy and the prim in main is not modified. 
You might consider returning the modified prim as a return value.

```
void adauga2(char *sir, NOD* &prim)
{ 
    int i;
    strcpy(sir, strrev(sir));
    for (i=0; i < strlen(sir); i++)
        adauga(prim, sir[i]-'0');
}
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot! Wish I could upvote you but I don't have enough reputation :d

Comment: Flagging it as the answer is fine. You're welcome. :)